# Delaying Tasks in a method in Android

Tags: android, timer, scheduling, sleep, postdelayed

I have a robot that I want to control via bluetooth. I write on bluetooth socket asking the robot to move, if the robot reads my message sucessfully, it will send me a signal back saying that "I read you!". The problem is that it takes 3 seconds for the robot to respond. My ideal case is something like this

```
public class Robot {

    private boolean lastMsgWasRead;

    public boolean askMeWalk(){

    lastMsgWasRead=false;
    writeToBluetooth("Walk");

    // somehow wait 3 seconds at least.

    if (lastMsgWasRead){
        return true; // sucessful walk
    }else{
        return false; // the robot didn't hear you 
    }

    }

}
```

Now here is it my question: is there anything that I could use for:

- somehow wait 3 seconds at least.

I have already read about `postDelayed, timer, and ScheduledExecutorService` and etc...

but none of them actually helps me to find my return value which is very important to me. If I ever want to use postDelayed or so, I cannot set the return value as they run on independent threads.

I tried Thread.sleep(3000), but I realized that it does make any difference as it stops the main thread - so the handler does not get a change to update the lastMsgWasRead value during that `3000ms.`

Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

So you could do something that is sort of a hybrid. 3 seconds is a long time. So you never really want your main thread to wait that long. Maybe something like this.

```
public class AwesomeActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {


 private Handler handler;
 private AsyncTask<?,?,?> task;

 public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    handler = new Handler(this);
    // Send your data to the robot via an async task
    // Have the async task and listen for the data in the background
    task = new TalkAndListen() {
        public void onPostExecute(String response) {
             // The postExecute() method joins back to the main thread
             // and cancels the async callback you fired off earlier on success
             handler.removeMessages(0);
             // Yay success!
        }
    }.execute("Walk");

   handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 3000);
 }

 public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {

    if (message.what == 0) {
       // Sad Trombone, kill off the async thread, 3 secs has passed
       task.cancel(true);
    }
 }

 private static class TalkAndListen extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   // This is done on a background thread  
   public String doInBackground(String... words) {
       for (String word : words) {
          writeToBluetooth(word);
       }
       return readFromBluetooth();
   }
   // This is the string returned from doInBackground() passed to the main thread
   public void onPostExecute(String responseSignal) {

   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created I class a time ago to help in this cases, you can see it [here](https://github.com/dragondgold/MultiWork/tree/master/MultiWork/src/main/java/com/bluetoothutils/andres). It allows you to send data and wait for it Asynchronously. For example you would use it on this way:

```
BluetoothHelper mBluetoothHelper = new BluetoothHelper(this, "bluetoothDeviceName", false, null);
mBluetoothHelper.setConnectionDialog(true);   // Shows a dialog while connecting
mBluetoothHelper.connect(true);               // Connect to Bluetooth device
```

So, on this way you connect to the Bluetooth device, now to receive data you need to implement `OnNewBluetoothDataReceivedListener`:

```
mBluetoothHelper.setOnNewBluetoothDataReceived(this);

// Called when you receive data from Bluetooth
@Override
public boolean onNewBluetoothDataReceivedListener(InputStream mBTIn, OutputStream mBTOut) {

}
```

So you don't have to wait anything, it will be called Asynchronously when you receive data. To send data:

```
mBluetoothHelper.write(data);
```

You will have to implement the method to write `String` using this method. So you will need

- OnNewBluetoothDataReceivedListener.java
- BluetoothHelper.java
- You will also need `DeviceList.java` with [device_list.xml](https://github.com/dragondgold/MultiWork/blob/master/MultiWork/src/main/res/layout/device_list.xml%20%22%22) in layout and this Strings in `strings.xml`

> ```
> <string name="scanning">                  Scanning…</string>
> <string name="select_device">             Select device</string>
> <string name="none_paired">                   No paired devices</string>
> <string name="none_found">                    No devices were found</string>
> <string name="title_paired_devices">      Paired devices</string>
> <string name="title_other_devices">           Other available devices</string>
> <string name="button_scan">                   Scan</string>
> ```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

> ```
>       <activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
>               android:label="@string/select_device"
>               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
>               android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
>       </activity>
> ```

You need this because when you scan to connect to a Bluetooth device it shows you a list of available devices, you can modify it in `BluetoothHelper.java` if you don't want it.